# Vector subscript out of range C++ merge sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, mergesort

I'm trying to implement a simple merge sort in c++ but I keep hitting this error:

[image]

My code:

```
void merge(vector<int> &data,int left,int mid,int right) {
vector<int> L, R, v;
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i <  mid - left + 1; i++) {
    L.push_back(v[left + i]);
}
for (j = 0; j < right - mid; j++) {
    R.push_back(v[mid + j + 1]);
}
i = j = 0;
int k = left;
while (i < L.size() && j < R.size()) {
    if (L[i] < R[j]) {
        v[k++] = L[i++];
    }
    else {
        v[k++] = R[j++];
    }
}

while (i < L.size()) {
    v[k++] = L[i++];
}
while (j < R.size()) {
    v[k++] = R[j++];
}

vector<int>::const_iterator iter = v.begin();

for (; iter != v.end(); ++iter)
{
    data[left++] = *iter;
}
}

void mergeSort(vector<int> &v, int left, int right) {
if (left < right) {
    int mid = (left + right) / 2;
    mergeSort(v, left, mid);
    mergeSort(v, mid + 1, right);
    merge(v, left, mid, right);
}
}
```

Call in main: `mergeSort(numbers,0,numbers.size());`  where numbers is a vector with some numbers.

How can I solve this assertion failure and what does vector subscript out of range mean?

Comment: That's a crash. You use a debugger to find out where in your code it happens, and to examine involved variables to make sure they seem alright. So start with pressing the "Retry" button to debug go into the debugger.

Comment: That said, the message "vector subscript out of range" should be a pretty big hint about what's happening. And a good point to start when [debugging your code](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @Raul Marinau The reason of the error is the very bad code of the function merge. It is a rule of programming that a bad code contains a bug.

Comment: @Raul Marinau At least there are typos in the function merge. Instead of the vector v there must be the vector data in the loops. for (i = 0; i <  mid - left + 1; i++) {
    L.push_back(v[left + i]);
}
for (j = 0; j < right - mid; j++) {
    R.push_back(v[mid + j + 1]);
}

Answer (score 0):

Is is a law of programming that a bad code contains bugs.:)

For starters you should use the type `std::vector<int>::size_type` instead of the type `int`.

There are typos in the function merge. It is evident that instead of the vector `v` there must be used the vector `data` in the loops because the vector `v` is empty.

```
void merge(vector<int> &data,int left,int mid,int right) {
vector<int> L, R, v;
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i <  mid - left + 1; i++) {
    L.push_back(v[left + i]);
}
for (j = 0; j < right - mid; j++) {
    R.push_back(v[mid + j + 1]);
}
```

Also after the loops the number of vector elements is one greater than the actual number of elements.

Consider the following test program that uses the loops from the function `merge`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void merge( std::vector<int> &data,  
            std::vector<int>::size_type left,
            std::vector<int>::size_type mid,
            std::vector<int>::size_type right ) 
{
    std::vector<int> L, R;

    for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i <  mid - left + 1; i++ ) 
    {
            L.push_back( data[left + i] );
    }

    for ( std::vector<int>::size_type j = 0; j < right - mid; j++ ) 
    {
            R.push_back( data[mid + j + 1]);
    }

    std::cout << L.size() << '\t' << R.size() << std::endl;
}

void mergeSort( std::vector<int> &v, 
                std::vector<int>::size_type left, 
                std::vector<int>::size_type right ) 
{
    if ( left < right ) 
    {
        auto mid = ( left + right ) / 2;
        merge( v, left, mid, right );
    }
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v( { 1, 2 } );

    mergeSort( v, 0, v.size() );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
2   1
```

though the original vector `v` contains only `2` elements.